# How to dynamically create two dropdown box with php and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get, dropdown

Pls kindly help me solve this problem. Basically, I want to create two drop down menus that communicate with each other. The first drop down menu will include US states. After the user selects a state, I want the cities in the other menu to show up. How would i go about doing this (using html, css, php, and/or javascript).  I have been having problem with the $_get (svalue). it is giving error Notice: Undefined index: svalue in C:\xampp\htdocs\online\ajax-getvalues.php on line 82. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

my table look like this
table-delcity

```
city_id  |  cityname  |  svalue
_____________________________________
1        |   Lagos    |  texas
____________________________________
2        |   Abuja    |  Fct
_____________________________________
3        |   Niger    |  mali
```

and my code

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "apple", "applebed", "gilmorewines");

//$selectvalue = mysql_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['svalue']);
    $selectvalue= mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['svalue'],$connection );



mysqli_select_db($connection, "gilmorewines");
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT cityname  FROM delcity WHERE 'svalue'='$selectvalue' ")or die(mysql_error());

echo '<option value="">Please select...</option>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['cityname'].'">' . $row['cityname'] . "</option>";
    //echo $row['drink_type'] ."<br/>";
  }

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($connection);



?>
```

Ajax script

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var list_target_id = 'list-target'; //first select list ID
  var list_select_id = 'list-select'; //second select list ID
  var initial_target_html = '<option value="">Please select a colour...</option>'; //Initial prompt for target select

  $('#'+list_target_id).html(initial_target_html); //Give the target select the prompt option

  $('#'+list_select_id).change(function(e) {
    //Grab the chosen value on first select list change
    var selectvalue = $(this).val();

    //Display 'loading' status in the target select list
    $('#'+list_target_id).html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');

    if (selectvalue == "") {
        //Display initial prompt in target select if blank value selected
       $('#'+list_target_id).html(initial_target_html);
    } else {
      //Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
      $.ajax({url: 'ajax-getvalues.php?svalue='+selectvalue,
             success: function(output) {
                //alert(output);
                $('#'+list_target_id).html(output);
            },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
          }});
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate second dropdown using jQuery & Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752818/populate-second-dropdown-using-jquery-ajax)

Comment: I can't find where `$_get (svalue)` is used in the above code?

Comment: You didn't define any html elements in your php code with an id='list-target' -> that's why jQuery can't find an element with that ID.  As an aside, you probably shouldn't post your DB connect info on stackoverflow. Also, you probably should use prepared mySQL statements when passing $_GET variables to your DB.